# Android Animation "Rolling in"

Tags: android, rotation, translate-animation

I am making an animation that a coin roll in from the left.

So far I can get it spin by RotateAnimation and move by TranslateAnimation.

Now I am stuck trying getting these 2 running at the same time.

```
{
    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,-1f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    setCoinAppear.addAnimation(animation);
}
{
    Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0, 720, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    setCoinAppear.addAnimation(animation);
}
```

If I start them at the same time, the coin will show a converging circular motion around the center.

Any suggestion on how to get it done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an AnimationSet and add each of those animations to the set like this:

```
AnimationSet rollingIn = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation moving = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,-1f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
moving.setDuration(5000);

rollingIn.addAnimation(moving);

Animation rotating = new RotateAnimation(0, 720, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotating.setDuration(5000);

rollingIn.addAnimation(rotating);

setCoinAppear.startAnimation(rollingIn);
```